# Elements are not stacking vertically on smaller screens, they're just shrinking in width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've used flex to make the height of three columns match the column with the most content.

However, the page is now not responsive.

*When I reduce the size of the browser to emulate a mobile device the elements do not stack vertically, but just shrink in width.*

Anyone have a solution?

Here's an example:

```css
    .w3-row {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-align-items: stretch;
      align-items: stretch;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">

<body>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-third w3-indigo w3-card-2 w3-margin w3-padding">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>More text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-card-2 w3-margin w3-padding">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-third w3-red w3-card-2 w3-margin w3-padding">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <p>More text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there's an option for wrapping , try `flex-wrap:wrap`

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is `flex-wrap: wrap` on your container.

The default is `flex-wrap: nowrap`, which forces flex items to remain on a single line. Like in your example, flex items will just shrink their widths, but cannot wrap.

Try this:

```
.w3-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;   /* initial setting; can be omitted */
    flex-wrap: wrap;        /* allow container to have multiple lines */
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qfdhjpgs/)

Reference:

- [5.2. Flex Line Wrapping: the `flex-wrap` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-wrap-property)